# Can't find Vaadin ClassResource

Tags: scala, tomcat, vaadin

I'm trying to use the Vaadin ClassResource class to load my database connection properties from a file that will be deployed with the WAR, but I can't seem to find the file.  I am using Vaadin 6.5.2, Tomcat 7.0.6, and I've placed my "app.properties" file in the same package as my Application main file.

My code is in Scala. Here's what I try:

```
val cr = new ClassResource("app.properties",this) // "this" is the application
debug("resource mimeType = {}",cr.getMIMEType)
debug("resource bufferSize = {}", cr.getBufferSize)
debug("resource cacheTime = {}",cr.getCacheTime)
debug("resource fileName = {}", cr.getFilename)
val ds = cr.getStream
if (ds != null) {  
  debug("download stream bufferSize = {}", ds.getBufferSize)
  debug("download stream cacheTime = {}",ds.getCacheTime)

  val is = ds.getStream // get InputStream

  if (is != null) {
    val props = new Properties
    props.load(is)
    val dbHost = props.get("db.host").asInstanceOf[String]
    val dbName = props.get("db.name").asInstanceOf[String]
    val dbPort = props.get("db.port").asInstanceOf[String]
    val dbUser = props.get("db.user").asInstanceOf[String]
    val dbPass = props.get("db.pass").asInstanceOf[String]
    val dbUri = props.get("db.uri").asInstanceOf[String]
  } else {
    debug("Input stream was null")
  }
} else {
  debug("Download stream was null")
}
```

And here is the result:

```
08:51:59.617 ["http-bio-8084"-exec-11] DEBUG c.sentientswarm.propdesk.AppConfig$ - resource mimeType = application/octet-stream
08:51:59.620 ["http-bio-8084"-exec-11] DEBUG c.sentientswarm.propdesk.AppConfig$ - resource bufferSize = 0
08:51:59.621 ["http-bio-8084"-exec-11] DEBUG c.sentientswarm.propdesk.AppConfig$ - resource cacheTime = 86400000
08:51:59.621 ["http-bio-8084"-exec-11] DEBUG c.sentientswarm.propdesk.AppConfig$ - resource fileName = app.properties
08:51:59.621 ["http-bio-8084"-exec-11] DEBUG c.sentientswarm.propdesk.AppConfig$ - download stream bufferSize = 0
08:51:59.621 ["http-bio-8084"-exec-11] DEBUG c.sentientswarm.propdesk.AppConfig$ - download stream cacheTime = 86400000
08:51:59.621 ["http-bio-8084"-exec-11] DEBUG c.sentientswarm.propdesk.AppConfig$ - Input stream was null
```

I've tried placing the config file in various locations including the top of src, inside the top of the VAADIN folder that holds themes, and where it currently is (in the same package as the main Application), but the results are always the same.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong???

Comment: What do you use to build the war-file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how we do it.

```
        InputStream is=null;
    try
    {
        is=Application.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Application.properties");
    }
    catch(Exception x)
    {
        log.error("Error loading 'Application.properties' properties",x);
        return null;
    }

    if (is!=null)
    {
        try
        {
            Properties props=new Properties();
            props.load(is);
            return(props);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            log.error("Error reading properties 'Application.properties' ",e);
        }
    }

    return(null);
```

However to be fair, we don't create wars and keep our application unexploded.
Keep in mind that `Application.class` is not the Vaadin application but our own wrapper around the Vaadin application.

Answer (score 0):

I copied .properties file into application context directory and read it in following way

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new FileInputStream(getContext().getBaseDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/application.properties"));
```

Called above code from application class.